# ListBox Add from button

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok so I have a button in my web Browser(form1) called bookmark. I want it to add the url to the listbox in Form3. When I try I get an error for something wrong with it.

This error:

[image]

But I changed my code to this:

```
Form3.AC.listBox1.Items.Add(getCurrentBrowser().Url.ToString());
```

Still error

Full code:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3.AC.listBox1.Items.Add(getCurrentBrowser().Url.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass in an instance of Form3, but your not using that instance, change your code to this and give it a go:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form.AC.listBox1.Items.Add(getCurrentBrowser().Url.ToString());
}
```

**Update:**

When you instantiate the AddFavourites class/form you pass in an instance of Form3 into the constructor:

```
var frmAddFavs = new AddFavorites(new Form3());
frmAddFavs.Show();
```

Or if the AddFavorites form is launched/instantiated by Form3:

```
var frmAddFavs = new AddFavorites(this);
frmAddFavs.Show();
```

In the constructor of AddFavorites you store a copy of the Form3 instance:

```
public AddFavorite(Form3 form)
{
InitializeComponent();
this._form = form; //<- here we store the Form3 instance
}
```

In you button click you are calling `Form3.AC.Listbox...` but Form3 in that context hasn't been instantiated.

My answer is saying to use the private member variable `_form` which is an instance of Form3.

**Update 2:**

> I dont understand that. I get the error for _form

Make sure you pass in a instance of Form3 to the constructor of AddFavorites. If you dont pass in a Form3 argument, it will call the default constructor (even though its not visible in your code). Tip: When you overload a classes constructor and remove the parameterless one, the parameterless one is actually still available.

So dont do this:

```
  var frmAddFavs = new AddFavorites();
  frmAddFavs.Show();
```

which is the same as this:

```
  var frmAddFavs = new AddFavorites(NULL);
  frmAddFavs.Show();
```